# how to define parse property in node js

Tags: node.js

```
> simpleserver@1.0.0 start C:\projects\simpleserver
> node server.js

C:\projects\simpleserver\server.js:19
        var url = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\projects\simpleserver\server.js:19:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:533:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:103:23)
```

Comment: please reply of  my question

Comment: Please [read this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a _good_ question. Also, the tag `git-bash` has nothing to do with your question at all (so I removed it). Lastly: your comment is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code, the problem is that you're defining a new variable named `url` that is overriding the `url` module.

```
 var url = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
 var url;
 url = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
```

So, whatever value `url` had from a higher scope, you just overrode it and created a new local variable named `url` that is `undefined` and thus has no `.parse()` property.

---

You can fix it by just renaming one of the variables to have a different name as in:

```
var localUrl = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
```

Comment: url.js:90
    throw new TypeError("Parameter 'url' must be a string, not " + typeof url);
    ^

TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
    at Url.parse (url.js:90:11)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:84:5)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\projects\simpleserver\server.js:20:21)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)

Comment: @ShashiRanjan - You should learn how to do your own elementary debugging before asking here.  It looks like that new error message is telling you that the value you are passing to `url.parse()` is not a string.  So, apparently, `req.url` is not what it should be.  You can see what it is yourself by inserting a `console.log(req)` and `console.log(req.url)` to see what those values are.  You don' t show enough of your code for us to have any idea what they are.

Comment: @ShashiRanjan - Multiline code is not readable in comments here on stack overflow.  If you have a new question about some new code, I'd suggest you put it in a new question where you can properly format it and make it readable and then people can answer.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that `url` is undefined. Most likely, you meant to use the standard `url` module, so you need to do something like

```
var url_m = require('url'); // near the top of your file
... later ...
var url = url_m.parse(req.url).pathname;
```

I suggested the name `url_m` to indicate that it's a module, but you can replace that name with anything else. In some examples you will see `var url = require('url');`, but I didn't do that since you have a different variable that you are also calling `url`.

Comment: showing error again                                                                                                url.js:90
    throw new TypeError("Parameter 'url' must be a string, not " + typeof url);
    ^

TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
    at Url.parse (url.js:90:11)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:84:5)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\projects\simpleserver\server.js:20:21)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:172:7)